# When are the () required in a method call in ruby/rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In a helper I've got the code:

```
signed_in? ? link_to("Sign out", signout_path, :method => :delete) : link_to("Sign in", signin_path)
```

However the same thing can be written:

```
if(signed_in?)
  link_to 'Sign Out', signout_path, :method => :delete
else
  link_to 'Sign In', signin_path
end
```

In the second case, the parens for the method call aren't needed, in the first case they are. Why is that?

Comment: Because in the first case they syntax would be ambiguous. The ternary operator goes like this: condition ? if_true : if_false. If you didn't have parenthesis, it would be like you are trying to have more than one statement in the true part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need parens when there is no ambiguity in the function calls. For instance:

```
  foo 1, 2 resolves to foo(1,2)
```

and something like  `foo 1, bar 2 would be foo(1,bar(2))`, but what about `foo 1, bar 2, 3` that could go to either `foo(1,bar(2,3))` or `foo(1,bar(2),3)`

So in the last example you would need to put in the parens yourself to tell ruby what you actually want it to do.

Also, if you ever want to call a method on the return value of the method you'll need parens too
i.e `foo(1,2).bar`

Answer (score -1):

I think it just style of writing code..

i prefer option 1 , because it only using 1 line..